# Hyperledger new user register

Tags: hyperledger

Hyperledger has membership service, which keeps some initial members in the membersrvs.yaml file, e.g lukas, jim etc.

Then the user has to log into the network, by posting to restapi /registrar the enrollmentid and secret.

My question is how to create new user for the network for the users that are not defined in the CA? It seems admin user can do that, but how to invoke the /registrar api with the admin security context?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

REST api /registrar can be used only to log in to the network. If you would like to add new user to membership service you have 2 options:

1. Add new record to membersrvc.yaml, reset cluster state by removing  /var/hyperledger/production, and restarting membership service. In this case Information about new users will be imported at first start.
2. You can use Node.js SKD and add new user as it shown in this example for Fabric v0.6: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/ceefb12425b7ccb09fc0f88dc78d395a459dca55/sdk/node/test/unit/registrar.js

Comment: thats a dead link

Comment: Soon a Java SDK will be available

Comment: OP specifically asked how to do it *apart* from adding a record to membersrvc.yaml- why did the OP accept this answer? the incentive mechanism of rewarding people for accepting answers is about as good as this answer is. i.e. not very good

Comment: The answer was acceptable on Sep 2016, when there were just 2 options: via membership.yml and few examples for Node.js SDK (both of them were mentioned). I am sure that now, especially for v1.0, there are better example (Thanks to zhaochy for another answer below). You are welcome to post your version to keep this thread up-to-date.

Answer (score 5):

Update my answer for Fabric 1.0 alpha version.

Fabric 1.0 use Fabric-ca for authority check.

Fabric CA consist of both a server and a client component.
And fabric-ca server and fabric-ca client can be deployed to different servers after configure the TLS-cert.

there also exist 3 ways:
1. when start the fabric-ca server, add a new user at the configure file.
2. register a new user by fabric-ca client. The user performing the register request must be currently enrolled, and also this
registrar must have the proper authority to register the type of user being registered. The registrar must have been enrolled with attribute "hf.Registrar.DelegateRoles".
The DelegateRoles attribute specifies the types this registrar is allowed to register.
3. Using the java sdk or nodejs sdk. The sdk now works well with fabric.

here is a sample usage with java sdk:

```java
import org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.User;

public class SampleUser implements User, Serializable {
  // Sample User implementation go here
   ...
}
```

```java
private static final String FABRIC_CA_SERVICES_LOCATION = "http://localhost:7054";

HFCAClient ca_client;

try{

ca_client = new HFCAClient(FABRIC_CA_SERVICES_LOCATION, null);

SampleUser admin = new SampleUser("name","orgName","role");
if (!admin.isEnrolled()) {
    // Admin is the bootstrap user defined at fabric-ca server configure file, so we just enroll admin here.
    admin.setEnrollment(ca_client.enroll(admin.getName(), "adminPassword"));
    admin.setMPSID(org.getMSPID());
    System.out.println("Admin enroll success");
}
SampleUser user = new SampleUser("name","orgName","role");
System.out.println("register user ...");
if (!user.isRegistered()) {
    // here RegistrationRequest accepts two params, the first is userName, the second is the department of the user
    RegistrationRequest rr = new RegistrationRequest(user.getName(), "org.department");

    String password = ca_client.register(rr, admin);
    System.out.println("register success, and get password from ca server: " + password);
    // db.store(user,password)
}
catch (Exception e){
}
}
```